# Can we generalise groupoids to monoid-oids?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, groupoids

Groups correspond to one object categories where every morphism is an isomorphism. Monoids correspond to one object categories.

Groupoids correspond to small categories where every morphism is an isomorphism. So what algebraic structure corresponds to a general small category? What is a "monoid-oid".

Comment: I don't think there's really more of an answer than 'a monoid-oid is a category.'

Comment: One can define classes of categories which include all groupoids and all one-object categories but not all categories, but it is not clear which one to choose without some other desideratum.

Comment: Well, a *small* catagory.

Comment: For all the closers of the question, I would just like to point out that this question would certainly be considered worthy on the *categories* mailing list (admittedly, nothing catches the interest of category theorists more than a triviality with potential to get out of hand). Perhaps the particular question itself is not very illuminating, but it directly leads to thinking about how we generalize many other constructions (see the link to *horizontal categorification* in my answer) – and I don't see mere undergrads doing such things.

Answer (score 8):

You may wish to consult the nLab page on [horizontal categorification](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horizontal+categorification) which explains the general idea and has many examples to illustrate it. One of them is *monoidoid*, and they have to say this about it:

> And *an exception to the rule*: a many-object monoid is not called a monoidoid – but is called a category!

Comment: I guess I should just be grateful that a semigroup-with-identity is not rechristened a "mon"

Comment: @YemonChoi a mono**i**d without **i**dentity is a monod, no? /s

Comment: @DavidRoberts And a heap (or torsor) is a grup, I suppose...